# How can I select data from different tables?

Tags: mysql, select, join, union

I have these tables:

ARTICLE, ARTICLE_has_tag, TAG, POST_ARTICLE and USER.

I would like to take all from ARTICLE, then the name of one tag (even that they have more than one), the number of comments and the user who made it. ¿Is it possible? ¿Should I do more than one query?

```
ARTICLE
`ID_ARTICLE` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TITLE_ARTICLE` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `SUBTITLE_ARTICLE` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `REFEREE_ARTICLE` text,
  `LINEUP_ARTICLE` text,
  `LINEUP_OPPONENT_ARTICLE` text,
  `CARD_ARTICLE` text,
  `CARD_OPPONENT_ARTICLE` text,
  `CHANGE_ARTICLE` text,
  `CHANGE_OPPONENT_ARTICLE` text,
  `GOALS_ARTICLE` text,
  `CONTENT_ARTICLE` text NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_ARTICLE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `IMAGE_ARTICLE` text,
  `MATCH_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_ARTICLE`),

ARTICLE_has_TAG
`ARTICLE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TAG_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,

POST_ARTICLE
`ID_POST_ARTICLE` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CONTENT_POST_ARTICLE` text NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_POST_ARTICLE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ARTICLE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,

TAG
`ID_TAG` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME_TAG` text NOT NULL,

USER
`ID_USER` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USERNAME_USER` text NOT NULL,
  `FIRSTNAME_USER` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LASTNAME_USER` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL_USER` text NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD_USER` text NOT NULL,
  `TYPE_USER` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `IMAGE_USER` varchar(100) DEFAULT '245x342.jpg',
  `KEY_USER` text NOT NULL,
  `ACTIVATED_USER` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `CREATED_USER` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Comment: yes, its possible, you can try to learn sql, write query to do this and in case of some problems - post question here

Comment: *Please* use Google next time. When I copy your exact thread title, I get tons of results explaining just what you need: https://www.google.at/search?q=HOW+CAN+I+SELECT+DATA+FROM+DIFFERENT+TABLES%3F&oq=HOW+CAN+I+SELECT+DATA+FROM+DIFFERENT+TABLES%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.239j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Looks to me (from the tags you have used) that you know the answer you are looking for include the `SELECT` keyword and the `JOIN`.  Give it a go yourself

Answer (score -1):

You can do this either by a JOIN or Sub-query

[Sub-query documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html)

[JOIN documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)